# C++ OpenCV 0xC0000005 error while reading from camera

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, access-violation

As said I get a 0xC0000005 reading access violation error realted to VSFilter.dll when I try to get a frame from the camera. I've tried different sample code found online and in the OpenCV documentation but I still get the error. For example this is the code I'm using now:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened()) return -1;

    Mat frame;

    namedWindow("Camera",1);

    while(1)
    {
        cap >> frame;
                
        imshow("Camera", frame);

        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And in the output there are this two errors (a first-chance exeption and an unhandled exeption, sorry for the italian):

```
Eccezione first-chance in 0x000007FEEB115791 (VSFilter.dll) in OpenCV.exe: 0xC0000005: violazione di accesso durante la scrittura del percorso 0x000000000468E000.
Eccezione non gestita in 0x000007FEEB115791 (VSFilter.dll) in OpenCV.exe: 0xC0000005: violazione di accesso durante la scrittura del percorso 0x000000000468E000.
```

So the code is pretty simple and it shouldn't be the problem, I am wondering why the error is related to VSFilter.dll (VobSub & TextSub filter for DirectShow/VirtualDub/Avisynth)?

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.5 and VisulaStudio 2012.

---

#### Solved

I've downloaded VSFilter.dll and replaced the original one in Windows/system32/, now everything work!

Answer (score 1):

any chance, you ended up in "dll hell" ?

like:

1. linking release code against debug dll's  ( or the other way round )
2. linking 32bit code against 64bit dll's    ( or the other way round )
3. linking vc9 code against vc10 dll's   ( .. i hope, you get the pattern, now )

Comment: i've checked the linker properties and the c/c++ ones and the directories are the right ones, in debug i've linked the -d.lib libraries.
what do you mean by "linking vc9 code against vc10 dll's"?
i'm quite a newbie.

Comment: ok, ok. not so easy, this time. thanks for doing the checklist anyway.

Comment: I've tried to load an image from a file and it worked, i don't think that OpneCV is the problem, rather the VSFilter.dll, why is my program using it?

Comment: you could try to sidestep videocapture/dshow by specifying VideoCapture cap(CAP_VFW + 0); // using vfw instead

Comment: it was a "bad" VSFilter.dll i had in system32, it was 1.5M now i've replaced it with another that is about 700k and everything works fine!
Thanks for the help!